# crawler in multiple websites of sales

Tags: php, python, web-crawler

This is my general idea: *Search in multiples websites of sales (ebay for example) to find the average price of an ipad 2 in the last month.*

I only want some directions to do something like this. The language can be PHP or Python, and an open source project can be used.

The problem is that a system like that needs some custom parameters, like date intervals and name of the object, at least.

So will I need a custom crawler for each website?

How can I associate the value to the product?

What sort of problems might I have with these sites of sales?

Well, I really need some advice about the correct way to do something similar.

Comment: Try writing the crawler and *then* ask if you have a specific problem. Also, I'd use the Ebay API instead of crawling Ebay.

Comment: @Blender the ebay is just an example. I need a general idea and i don't have a specific problem at this stage.

Comment: So what's your question? If you're leaning towards Python, take a look at [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

Comment: @Blender Some advice from someone who has experience in something similar.

Answer (score 1):

> So probably i will need a custom crawler for each website?

No, you'll need to customise some aspect of it for each website but the underlying engine will remain the same. And you only want some information, so you'll have to customise it to get only that.

> How associate the value to the product?

You just scraped that data, it's up to you to manage that aspect of it. But if you are scraping product X then you keep a list of prices for that product and (for example) average the contents of that list to get the average price. How you associate that list to a product depends on your underlying database implementation.

> Can I have some problems with these sites of sales?

Yes, of course, if the site changes then your scraper may stop working. This is why it's better to always use an API as then you do not depend on the structure of the page not changing to obtain your content.

> Well, I really need some advice about the correct way to do something
>   similar.

Use an API in preference to picking through HTML. Use existing tools rather then reinventing the wheel. 
http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

http://scrapy.org/

http://seleniumhq.org/

[Amazon API library for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884/amazon-api-library-for-python)